# why ngOnChanges() function not fired in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Could you, please, tell me why `ngOnChanges()` function is not fired in angular2?
I tried to change a `message` property using `@Input` but onchange event is not fired.

Here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/BOw5vazUUM8WNh9C1CNa?p=preview

```
export class Test implements OnInit,OnChanges{
  name:string;
  @Input() message;
  constructor() {
    console.log('==constructor==')
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  ngOnInit(){
     // this.myService.someMethod() 
       console.log('==ngOnInit==')
   }

    ngOnChanges() {
        console.log('onChange fired');

    }
}
```

Comment: actually it **is** fired in my console. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: ngOnChanges only fire when @Input reference changed

Comment: it is not firing ? this messge not display onChange fired

Comment: I try to change "Angular 2" text from input field ..but it not fired onchange event

Comment: not able to comment, hence putting it here... is your problem that ngOnInit getting fired before ngOnChanges? if yes, then it is by design. if the controller contains both ngOnInit and ngOnChanges, then first ngOnInit will be fired and then ngOnChanges.

Comment: no, you can not, ngOnChanges mean, property binding from parent to child changed reference

Comment: culd you please give some example and how I will achieve thsi

Comment: wait a minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you wanna binding data between parent and child, when child change `message`, parent will receive the updated value.

this is demo:

**app.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule,OnInit,OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {Test} from './test';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}} from parent</h2>
      <test [(message)]="name"></test>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit,OnChanges{
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    console.log('==constructor==')
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  ngOnInit(){
     // this.myService.someMethod() 
       console.log('==ngOnInit==')
   }

    ngOnChanges() {
        console.log('onChange fired');

    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule  ],
  declarations: [ App ,Test],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**test.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule,OnInit,OnChanges,Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
    <div>
     {{message}}
     <input type="text" [ngModel]= "message" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"/>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Test implements OnInit,OnChanges{
  name:string;
  @Input() message;

  @Output() messageChange = new EventEmitter('');
  constructor() {
    console.log('==constructor==')
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  ngOnInit(){
     // this.myService.someMethod() 
       console.log('==ngOnInit==')
   }

    ngOnChanges() {
        console.log('onChange fired');

    }
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.message = event;

    this.messageChange.emit(this.message);
  }
}
```

demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/nU9Qkuf7bwgSga7Ce2Wc?p=preview

this is custom two-way binding in Angular.

```
<test [(message)]="name"></test>
```

equivalent:

```
<test [message]="name"(messageChange)="message = $event"></test>
```

where `messageChange` is an event from child component.